# Get Multiple Elements from Different Pages Together

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

http://justin.derp.us/
http://justin.derp.us/coming-soon.php
http://justin.derp.us/countdown.html

I need all 3 of these pages in one, and I'm having the hardest time getting it done,
I've tried iFrames, but to no avail (I can get most of it, but then the buttons at the bottom of the home screen don't appear)

I've tried putting them all into one page, and gotten one big mess: the JavaScript and CSS start doing things together and messing up big time. [eg, the javascript "submit" would mess up the count down, and I'd have two submit buttons and couldn't get the right one to the right size etc etc]

So I'm asking, is there a simple way to do this..?

[image: MockUp]

Don't know if its allowed, but I'd gladly compensate anyone who helps me achieve this. [if its not allowed I'll edit this]

Comment: You could put them in some sort of iframe/frameset sorta thing.

Comment: I tried both, and The iframe seemed to do the best, but on the browser it would keep the "vertical scroll" for the second iframe, and the buttons at the bottom wouldn't show up.

Comment: And just putting the code after each other doesn't work? Weird, because there doesn't seem to be a collision of some sort..

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, why not use the jQuery Tabs UI Component? http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: I really, REALLY like that idea, and chances are I will use that in the HOME page once I'm done with the rest of it, but as for now, the coming soon page is all one screen, don't want multiple tabs.

Comment: edit: reverted to the old because the buttons wouldn't even show up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two things that would need to do if you are taking the iFrame approach:

First, you have to change the background color of your countdown clock page in order for it to look like it belongs with the other components.

Second, in between your "Coming Soon" and "Subscribe" texts, place this code:

```
<iframe src="countdown.html" width="450" height="130" frameborder="0">
TEXT FOR NON-COMPATIBLE BROWSERS HERE</iframe>
```

Also, you will need to adjust your CSS stylesheet so that the countdown clock is centered, because it will not be if use leave it like this.

Good luck!

Comment: You might also want to center the text under your clock, too.

Comment: Good start, and I did end up having this, I did not have the style sheet edited to make the clock center though, Everything was working except the buttons on the buttom.